# Auto clean mail folder with dovecot/sieve

Tags: dovecot, mailbox, sieve

Can I automatically clean a folder in my mailbox?
Let's say I want to automatically delete messages that are older than 3 months.
Does dovecot/sieve have this option?

Comment: on reddit someone also ask about auto clean. https://www.reddit.com/r/ProtonMail/comments/6v1x1b/is_it_possible_to_write_a_sieve_filter_to/

Answer (score 1):

## Apply sieve filter to mails older than x days

To archieve this goal you can use the commands `doveadm move`and `sieve-filter`. You could also use `doveadm expunge`but with this approac you can delete or move mails older than X days.

First move all files older than 7 days to a temporary folder, in this case it is named sieve-tmp:

```
doveadm move -u test1@example.com INBOX.sieve-tmp user test1@example.com mailbox INBOX BEFORE $(date -d "$now -7 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
```

The commands takes the following arguments:

`-u test1@example.com` the source users mailbox

`INBOX.sieve-tmp` the folder to copy the mails to (INBOX/tmp)

`user test1@example.com` the destination users mailbox, in my case the same as the source mailbox

`mailbox` a required keyword

`INBOX` the source folder, in this case the INBOX

`BEFORE $(date -d "$now -7 days" +%Y-%m-%d)` the search filter. This filter returns mails created before the date YYYY-MM-DD. The date command delivers the date, 7 day from now. You can replace 7 with any desired number.

Created a sieve script to apply on mails older than 7 days. I created it using roundcube and deactivated it in the interface so it does not get applied to incoming mails. I called it `7d`.

```
sieve-filter -e -W -C -u test1@example.com /var/mail/example.com/test1/sieve/7d.sieve INBOX.sieve-tmp
```

`-e` enables execution mode

`-W` enables write mode

`-C` forece compilation. The script is compiled to a binary.

`-u test1@example.com` runs the script for this user.

`/var/mail/example.com/test1/sieve/7d.sieve` path to the sieve script to be executed.

`INBOX.sieve-tmp` folder to execute the script on.

After this all the desired mails are processed and the rest can be moved back to the Inbox:

```
doveadm move -u test1@example.com INBOX user test1@example.com mailbox INBOX.sieve-tmp ALL
```

### Final script

```
#!/bin/bash
doveadm move -u test1@example.com INBOX.sieve-tmp user test1@example.com mailbox INBOX BEFORE $(date -d "$now -7 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
sieve-filter -e -W -C -u test1@example.com /var/mail/example.com/test1/sieve/7d.sieve INBOX.sieve-tmp
doveadm move -u test1@example.com INBOX user test1@example.com mailbox INBOX.sieve-tmp ALL
```

If you want another script processing mails older than X day, just copy this block and replace the time reference.

The script can be called once a day via a cron job:

```
crontab -e
```

```
0 0 * * * /opt/filter-my-mails.sh
```

Comment: I have no idea why this hasnt got more upvotes - it is the perfect answer.